# Maximum click length parameter in PAMGuard

Tags: pamguard, maximum-click-length

It is not clear for me why the maximum click length parameter of the click detector must be greater than the minimum click separation.

If the minimum click separation is the number of samples between consecutive clicks, and the maximum click length is the maximum length in samples that will have my click clip,then in the click clip I would see two clicks as it will consider more samples than the minimum separation between them

Answer (score 4):

The minimum click separation parameter is designed to keep a single click detected on multiple near-by hydrophones together and is nothing to do with consecutive clicks. e.g. if you had two hydrophones 3, apart to measure bearings, there is a delay of up to 2ms between the click arriving on one hydrophone then the other. Sampling at 48kHz, this would be up to 96 samples. Now imagine you've a short or quiet click which is only above threshold for 20 samples: it would be detected on one channel, then on the other channel creating two separate clicks. If that happens PAMGuard can no long estimate bearings from the time delay. For a small array used to measure bearings, the minimum click separation should therefore be set to the number of samples corresponding to the maximum time delay between hydrophones. For a larger array, consider detecting separately on each hydrophone.